# props unable to be reactive in vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-component, vue-props

I have the code below:

```
var CatShelter = {
    template:
'<vue-multiselect' +
' :options="options">' +
'<template> <i v-on:click="removeCats(option)"></i></span> </template>' +
'</vue-multiselect>' +,
props: {options: Array},
methods: {
removeCats: function (object) {
            self = this;
this.options.pop();
            $.ajax({
                type: "PATCH",
                url: //irrelevant,
                'data': //irrelveant,
                'dataType': 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    
                },
                error: function (result) {
                }
            });

}
}
}

},
```

Basically, when the icon is clicked it calls this ajax request which removes an option from vue multiselect through DB. This works fine. When I refresh, the changes occur. I wantto be able to remove the options in real time. The options prop is essentially an array of the objects. How can I get vue to update the prop without refreshing which adjusts the vue multiselect?

**UPDATES **

Here's my real multiselect with your implemented changes.

```
'<vue-multiselect' +
        ' :options.sync="options"' +
        '<template slot="tag" slot-scope="{ option }"><span class="multiselect__tag"><span><img class="option__image" :src="option.img" width="16px" style="color: #ffffff;" /></span> [[ option.displayName ]] <i aria-hidden="true" tabindex="1" class="multiselect__tag-icon" v-on:click="removeTagAndRelevantTeamMembers(option)"></i></span> </template>' +
        '<template slot="option" slot-scope="{ option }">\n' +
        '      <img class="option__image" :src="option.img" width="16px" />\n' +
        '      <span class="option__desc">\n' +
        '        <span class="option__title">[[ option.displayName ]]</span>\n' +
        '      </span>\n' +
        '    </template>' +
        '</vue-multiselect>' +
```

Here's my real and implemented js:

```
 var me = this;
            $.ajax({
                type: "PATCH",
                url: //irrelv,
                'data': //irrelv,
                'dataType': 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    me.$emit('update:options', updated);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                }
            });
```

I am still unable to change the values in the multiselect when I press X
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. emit the click event to the parent, and call the ajax call in the parent - on success function, remove the item from the `options` array. this will update the `options` prop in the child component and update the options reactively
2. use `.sync` modifier: use your `removeCats` function as it is and on success function of ajax call emit: `this.$emit('update:options', <copy of the new options value with removed option>)`. and when you move the prop to the child component from you parent: `<child :options.sync="options" .../>`. this will update this.options prop and your options will update reactively as well.

you can read more about `.sync` in [vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier).

Comment: Hey do you mind checking out my update. Your help is really appreciated by me. I really need this.

Comment: I meant you use the .sync on the parent component of CatShelter. If your options list is in the same component with your multiselect you just need to delete the item from it. My answer is for when you get the options list as prop - and you can’t mutate a prop from the child component